# SpriteKit texture atlas leads to image artifacts and blank areas

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a SpriteKit game in which there's a shape created via `SKShapeNode(splinePoints:count:)`.

The shape has a `fillTexture`, loaded from a texture atlas via `textureNamed(_:)`.

In my texture atlas there are 5 images -- 1 of which is used for the shape.

If I use the regular .xcassets folder instead of an atlas, the shape is textured correctly. So it's definitely an issue with the atlas. Also, the texture works correctly if it's the only image in the atlas. It's when I add additional images that the problem occurs.

Here's the code that results in the *correct* texture:

```
            var splinePoints = mainData.getSplinePointsForGround()
            let ground = SKShapeNode(splinePoints: &splinePoints, count: splinePoints.count)
            let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "groundTexture")
            
            ground.fillTexture = texture
            
            ground.lineWidth = 1
            ground.fillColor = UIColor(Color.purple)
            ground.strokeColor = UIColor(Color.clear)
            
            addChild(ground)
```

**Expected results:**

The shape, which has a purple gradient image, should look like this (please ignore the dotted white line):

[image]

**Actual results:**

Instead, the shape looks like this, with strange blank areas and little artifacts from the other images located in the atlas:

[image]

Here's the version of code that uses the atlas:

```
            let textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "assets")
            var splinePoints = mainData.getSplinePointsForGround()
            let ground = SKShapeNode(splinePoints: &splinePoints, count: splinePoints.count)
            let texture = textureAtlas.textureNamed("groundTexture2.png")
            
            ground.fillTexture = texture
            
            ground.lineWidth = 1
            ground.fillColor = UIColor(Color.purple)
            ground.strokeColor = UIColor(Color.clear)
            
            addChild(ground)
```

Why is this problem happening, and how do I resolve it?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include the way in which it is successful? `If I use the regular .xcassets folder instead of an atlas, the shape is textured correctly. So it's definitely an issue with the atlas.`

Comment: @impression7vx I edited the question to include the code that works correctly using .xcassets. Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with doing it the "correct" way, the way that works?

Comment: @impression7vx Using a texture atlas is a performance enhancement that reduces the number of draw calls required to render the scene, as I understand it. So I'd like to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I've solved the problem, though I'm not sure *why* my solution works.

Instead of having a top-level `.atlas` folder, I've put a `.spriteatlas` folder *inside* `Assets.xcassets`.

For whatever reason, this results in the correct textures being shown without any nasty artifacts or transparent areas.